# count number of multiple observations within subgroups of each group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

Assume this is my df1 and I want to create df2.
So 0.67 shows the percent of x on Sat for A, and so on.

I am stuck on how to first group df1 by grp1 and then within grp1 group again by grp2 and then find n, % of each observation within this subgroups.
also, note that if there is no observation in the final subgroup it is assigned a value of 0.
I know I should provide my attempt before asking for some help with my problem, however, I am really stuck what is the approach for such this case, to begin with. Any help is appreciated.

```
df1 <- data.frame(grp1 = c(rep("A",4),rep("B",3), rep("C",4)),
                 obs = c("x", "x", "y", "z",     "x","y","y",    "x", "x","x", "y"),
                 grp2 = c("Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Fri", "Sat", "Fri", "Fri", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Fri"))

> df1
   grp1 obs grp2
1     A   x  Sat
2     A   x  Sat
3     A   y  Sat
4     A   z  Fri
5     B   x  Sat
6     B   y  Fri
7     B   y  Fri
8     C   x  Sat
9     C   x  Sat
10    C   x  Sat
11    C   y  Fri




   df2
   grp1 obs grp2 n percent
1     A   x  Sat 2    0.67
2     A   y  Sat 1    0.33
3     A   z  Sat 0    0.00
4     A   x  Fri 0    0.00
5     A   y  Fri 0    0.00
6     A   z  Fri 1    1.00
7     B   x  Sat 1    1.00
8     B   y  Sat 0    0.00
9     B   z  Sat 0    0.00
10    B   x  Fri 0    0.00
11    B   y  Fri 2    1.00
12    B   z  Fri 0    0.00
13    C   x  Sat 3    1.00
14    C   y  Sat 0    0.00
15    C   z  Sat 0    0.00
16    C   x  Fri 0    0.00
17    C   y  Fri 1    1.00
18    C   z  Fri 0    0.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps - get the frequency `count` `across` all the columns, expand the rows to fill with missing combinations, calculate the 'percent' by taking the `proportions` on the column 'n' after grouping by the 'grp' columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   count(across(everything())) %>% 
  complete(grp1, obs, grp2, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  group_by(grp1, grp2) %>%
  mutate(percent = proportions(n)) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 × 5
   grp1  obs   grp2      n percent
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>   <dbl>
 1 A     x     Fri       0   0    
 2 A     x     Sat       2   0.667
 3 A     y     Fri       0   0    
 4 A     y     Sat       1   0.333
 5 A     z     Fri       1   1    
 6 A     z     Sat       0   0    
 7 B     x     Fri       0   0    
 8 B     x     Sat       1   1    
 9 B     y     Fri       2   1    
10 B     y     Sat       0   0    
11 B     z     Fri       0   0    
12 B     z     Sat       0   0    
13 C     x     Fri       0   0    
14 C     x     Sat       3   1    
15 C     y     Fri       1   1    
16 C     y     Sat       0   0    
17 C     z     Fri       0   0    
18 C     z     Sat       0   0
```